# XPATH/XSLT - matching only the first following ancestor with a given attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to write an xpath expression that matches *only* the first following ancestor that contains a given attribute, but I can't find the appropriate xpath. A simplified XML example:

```
<root>
  <node href="L1_value_1">
    <node href="L2_value_1">
      <node href="L3_value_1">
        <node href="L4_value_1"/>
      </node>
    </node>
    <node/>
    <node href="L2_value_2"/>
    <node href="L2_value_3"/>
  </node>
  <node href="L1_value_2"/>
  <node href="L1_value_3"/>
</root>
```

For example, if I'm on the node containing href="L4_value_1", I want to return only the node with href="L2_value_2".  Unfortunately I can't find a the correct xpath. I've tried the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*/following-sibling::*[@href][1]"/>
```

--returns the first matching following sibling at *every* ancestor level, ie, nodes containing L2_value_2 and L1_value_2 in the example.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[1]/following-sibling::*[@href][1]"/>
```

--returns first matching following sibling at *only* the parent level, ie, nothing in the example.

How can I traverse up the tree as far as necessary and *only* capture the first match?

Comment: If `ancestor::*/following-sibling::*[@href][1]` gives you all the elements then `(ancestor::*/following-sibling::*[@href][1])[1]` gives you the first of those in document order. Not sure whether that is all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For you first expression, you would need to write it at this...

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="(ancestor::*/following-sibling::*[@href])[1]"/>
```

But perhaps you be better off using the `following` axis, rather than `following-sibling`, then you can do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following::*[@href][1]"/>
```

Comment: The expression `following::X` is equivalent to `ancestor::*/following-sibling::*/descendant-or-self::X`, which is not the same as `ancestor::*/following-sibling::X` because it selects cousins as well as uncles; the requirements aren't stated clearly enough to know which is correct.